# Attribute error: Object has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pytest, conftest

I am trying to set up test framework for a simple test to count the search results for a word on google.com. Here is how my framework looks:

```
repo
 |-pages
 |   |-google_launch_page.py
 |   |-google_search_results.py
 |
 |-tests
 |   |-conftest.py
 |   |-test_google.py
 |-conftest.py
```

Here is the `test_google.py`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pages.google_launch_page import LaunchPage
from pages.google_search_results_page import SearchResultPage
import time, re, pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class testgooglesite():
    def test_search_results(self):
        lp = LaunchPage(self.driver)
        lp.clickSearch("Chocolate")
        # test 1: there should be non-zero results
        result_element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='result-stats']")
        result_text = result_element.text
        numbers = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}(?:\s?\d{3})*', result_text)[0]
        result_count = int(''.join(numbers[0]))
        self.driver.close()
        assert result_count>0,"No results"

myobj = testgooglesite()
myobj.test_search_results()
```

And here is the `tests/conftest.py` (`repo/conftest.py` is empty):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request):
    service = Service()
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    driver.get('https://google.com/')
    webdriver.wait(driver,5)
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver
```

Finally, here is the error message:

```
tests\test_google.py:16: in test_search_results
    lp = LaunchPage(self.driver)
E   AttributeError: 'testgooglesite' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

I am assuming that pytest is likely overlooking `conftest.py` but I am unable to figure out the reason. Can someone please help?

Based on one suggestion in the comments, I have tried the following
`conftest.py`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
def driver(request):
    service = Service()
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    driver.get('https://google.com/')
    webdriver.wait(driver,5)
    driver.maximize_window() 
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield driver
```

And the test file:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pages.google_launch_page import LaunchPage
from pages.google_search_results_page import SearchResultPage
import time, re, pytest

# @pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver")
class testgooglesite():
    def test_search_results(self):
        lp = LaunchPage(driver)
        lp.clickSearch("Chocolate")
        # test 1: there should be non-zero results
        # find the corresponding element
        result_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='result-stats']")
        result_text = result_element.text
        print(result_text)
        numbers = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}(?:\s?\d{3})*', result_text)[0]
        result_count = int(''.join(numbers[0]))
        driver.close()
        assert result_count>0,"No results"

myobj = testgooglesite()
myobj.test_search_results()
```

Here, I tried to replace the fixture by yielding the driver and modifying the fixture to do `autouse=True`. But this gives me the error that `E   NameError: name 'driver' is not defined`.

Comment: Why do you think your test class has a `driver` instance variable? Maybe you want to yield the driver from your fixture?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I aimed to instantiate the driver to experiment with creating setup fixtures for my tests.  By yielding the driver, do you suggest adding something like `yield "driver"` at the end of the setup?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Probably rename your fixture to something like `driver`, set it to `autouse=True` if needed, and pass it to the tests where you need the driver.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I did the following changes:
For `conftest.py`:

`@pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)`

`def driver(request):`

`    service = Service()`

`    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()`
.
.
`    request.cls.driver = driver`
`    yield "driver"`



And for the test file only the decorater is changed to `@pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver")`

The error however persists

Comment: You mean `yield driver`, not `yield "driver"`, right? Also, you don't need `usefixtures` with `autouse`. Also, if you have replaced `self.driver` with `driver` from the passed fixture, how can you have the same error? You probably need to edit your question accordingly, otherwise this is difficult to understand.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen thank you for the feedback. I have now added my latest trial in the post. This shows an error that for lp = LaunchPage(driver)  name 'driver' is not defined.

Comment: Yes, you didn't pass the `driver` fixture into your test. Even it is auto-used, you need to pass it if you want to reference it, e.g. `def test_search_results(self, driver):`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I did that but now in the execution(which I added in the latest edit. I missed it in the last one) requires me to define a driver instance to be called as an argument. I mean these two lines: `myobj = testgooglesite()`  and `myobj.test_search_results()` the second line expects a driver argument now.  Do I need to call an instance of fixture now?

Comment: Ah wait - I thought you are using `pytest`? I missed this line. You should not call tests directly with pytest, just run `pytest`! Or if you really want to do this, call `pytest.main()` (which does the same as calling `pytest`).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Yes you are right. I am running only `pytest` in the CLI. And that's when I get this error `TypeError: testgooglesite.test_search_results() missing 1 required positional argument: 'driver'`. 

If I remove the class execution lines in the end(i.e.,`myobj = testgooglesite()` and `myobj.test_search_results()` ), pytest doesnt detect any test files.

Comment: Ah, I see - use `class TestGoogleSite` instead of `class testgooglesite`, otherwise pytest will not [recognize it as a test class by default](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery).

Comment: yes it worked! Actually it seems that was the only error. I would update this post with a submission :) Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MrBean Bremen, I found the error in my code. It was simply using the Class name in lowercase. It should be `class TestGoogleSite` instead of the usual `class testgooglesite`. It is necessary to start with `Test` whenever the class lacks an `__init__()` method(read [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery)).

The following code works:

`test_google.py`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pages.google_launch_page import LaunchPage
from pages.google_search_results_page import SearchResultPage
import time, re, pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class TestGoogleSite():
    def test_search_results(self):
        lp = LaunchPage(self.driver)
        lp.clickSearch("Chocolate")
        # test 1: there should be non-zero results
        result_element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='result-stats']")
        result_text = result_element.text
        numbers = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}(?:\s?\d{3})*', result_text)[0]
        result_count = int(''.join(numbers[0]))
        self.driver.close()
        assert result_count>0,"No results"
```

and `conftest.py`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request):
    service = Service()
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    driver.get('https://google.com/')
    webdriver.wait(driver,5)
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver
```